# jq curl contain output of two curl

Tags: arrays, dictionary, curl, jq

I use curl to have this answer :

```
curl -sX https://xx.com | jq -r '.res.out[].server // empty | {host: .host, description: .description}'
```

```
{ "host": "server1",
  "description": "server 1"
}
{ "host": "server2",
  "description": "server 2"
}
{ "host": "server3",
  "description": "server 3"
}
```

And I use a second curl to get the state of serveur if it is running or not. on second curl I need the name of host to get the state of server which I get on first curl, and I want to add also the description of server.

So, I would like to store the list of host and description on a map, to use on second curl

```
for host in ${array_host[@]}; do 
  echo "HOST: $host";
  echo "Description: $description"
  curl -sX https://xx.com/servers/$host | jq -r '.specInfo.resul.out[].server.operationalStatus //empty';
done
```

because on second curl, I have to loop on all server to get the state, for instance :

```
curl -sX https://xx.com/servers/server1 | jq -r '.specInfo.resul.out[].server.operationalStatus //empty';
RUNNING
curl -sX https://xx.com/servers/server2 | jq -r '.specInfo.resul.out[].server.operationalStatus //empty';
RUNNING
curl -sX https://xx.com/servers/server3 | jq -r '.specInfo.resul.out[].server.operationalStatus //empty';
NOT RUNNING
```

I expect somethink like that

```
HOST: Server1
Description: Server 1
RUNNING
HOST: Server2
Description: Server 2
RUNNING
HOST: Server3
Description: Server 3
NOT RUNNING
```

Comment: Instead of storing them in a shell array - store them in a multi-line string, one object per string: `echo '[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]' | jq '.[]' -c`. That way is naturally much easier to consume in shell scripts. And then you can parse every line individually and extract all the fields you need.

Comment: but I don't have common

Comment: You don't have _what_?

Answer (score 1):

Without more sample data, it's hard to test, but something like this should fit your needs:

```bash
curl … | jq -r '.res.out[].server | .host, .description' |
while read -r host; read -r desc; do
  printf 'HOST: %s\nDescription: %s\n' "$host" "$desc"
  curl … | jq …
done
```

Comment: "it does work for me" --- this is not a problem description. It's effectively what I suggested and based on _what_ you asked - there is no reason why this shouldn't do.